# How to redirect into another page after inserting form data in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a form with some `input` field.Now i want, if anyone `submit` this `form` then he will `redirect` to another page where i have written confirmation letter.I have searched but i can not find right answer of my issue.

**My controller:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $applicant = new Applicant();
    $applicant['name'] = $request->input('name');
    $applicant['sex'] = $request->input('sex');
    $applicant['marital_status'] = $request->input('marital_status');
    $applicant['date_of_birth'] = $request->input('date_of_birth');
    $applicant['email'] = $request->input('email');
    $applicant['fathers_name'] = $request->input('fathers_name');
    $applicant['mothers_name'] = $request->input('mothers_name');
    $applicant['spouses_name'] = $request->input('spouses_name');
    $applicant['nationality'] = $request->input('nationality');
    $applicant['present_add'] = $request->input('present_add');

    $applicant->save();
    \Session::flash('flash_message','Application has been successfully submitted.');
    return redirect(route('confirmationMsg'));
}
```

**My Route:**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'career'], function () {
    Route::get('apply', ['as' => 'addApplicant', 'uses' => 'ApplicantController@create']);
    Route::post('save', ['as' => 'saveApplicant', 'uses' => 'ApplicantController@store']);
    Route::get('submitted', ['as' => 'confirmationMsg', 'uses' => 'ApplicantController@store']);
});
```

I have got an error with this code:

> QueryException in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\NoticeBoard\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php
>   line 729: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'name' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `applicants` (`name`, `sex`,
>   `marital_status`

Could anyone help me where is the problem or how i do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if your input have the right name : <input name ="name" ...> your error doesn't getting input name

Comment: @DiegoCespedes its not a this kind of issue.Its redirecting issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
return redirect('your_route');

Route::get('your_route', function () {
    // return view from here or make a function call from a controller
});
```

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud actually, the code from your question is correct and `return redirect('your_route');` - code from this answer will not work, since you must pass URI to `redirect()` but not route name. If you want to use route name, you should use it as in your question `redirect(route('route_name'))` or `redirect()->route('route_name')`. And you error has nothing to do with routes and redirect anyway. You got DB related error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
return redirect()->route('confirmationMsg');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one below:

```
return Redirect::to(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see three answers which are saying about `redirect()` and `route()` usage, but your code is correct here. You even accepted one of these answers (why?).

The error says `name` (and probably few other) fields are empty, so you need to be sure you're passing those fields from the form. You can check this by using this code right in the beginning of the `store()` function:

```
dd($request->all());
```

Alternatively you can set one of few of these fields as `nullable()` in migration file:

```
$table->string('name')->nullable();
```

Comment: I have double call the method `ApplicantController@store` that's why when its going to `submitted` route then its again call the `ApplicantController@store` method.Now i have created another method and redirect to that method to show confirmation page.That's why i accepted that answer. My code now http://pastebin.com/3gPhy5Fz

Comment: Well still the answer isn't solving the problem and the code is wrong in it.

Comment: So tell me which one will be perfect approach to solve this issue? I think you understand my problem.

Comment: I guess in this case you should describe how did you solve the problem and tick your own answer. That's how StackOverflow works.